# Making the whole ion-item in an ItemReorder draggable

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, draggable

In my application I've got an [ItemReorder](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/ItemReorder/) as described in the docs:

```
<ion-list reorder="true">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

It works as intended, I can drag the `ion-items` by pointing at the reoder icon (see freehand circle):
[image]

Testing with potential users on a tablet I found out, many users don't see the icon at first and/or try to drag the `ion-item` without pointing at the icon. They expect the whole `ion-item` to be draggable:

[image]

How can I implement this? Any insight is appreciated!

---

I've already checked the docs twice, googled and found [this unanswered question on the ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-reorder-whole-ion-item-draggable/31849) and [this plugin for Ionic v1](https://github.com/kunder-lab/ionic-list-draggable-item). I also scanned the code on [Github](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/item/item-reorder.ts) without success.

Comment: Hi! Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the same problem =/

Comment: Hi there. Sadly no, if you're also interested in a solution feel free to vote up and/or [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Answer (score 0):

```
        The ideea of this css solution is to have the reorder icon invisible above the zone which you want to reorder. I have changed the icons to be on the right side <ion-list side="start"  and I have changed the css like this
```

Now for me it's working.

```
        ion-reorder{
            position: absolute;
            width: 22%;
            max-width: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
        }
```

The cons is that there is no more visible reorder icons.

Comment: Generally when you are giving answers, it is helpful to explain why your code fixes the problem, and include a short demo, which you can do by including a Codepen or a JSFiddle

Comment: This does not work for me: On the one hand, I'd like to keep the reoder icon visible, on the other I'm not able to drop the dragged item anymore