# Reorder whole ion-item draggable list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I need to reorder a list, and I can achieve that using `<ion-list reorder="true"></ion-list>`

[image: ion reorder list]

But I need to make the whole item draggable, so there is no need to use the ‘menu’ icon.

How can I do that?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702377/making-the-whole-ion-item-in-an-itemreorder-draggable

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder) you can make a whole item draggable, without using the menu icon, by wrapping it in a `<ion-reorder>`.

```html
<!-- Items wrapped in a reorder, entire item can be dragged -->
<ion-reorder>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>
      Item
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-reorder>
```